# error Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib when running python app

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.7

I am running my app and get this error- seems like it's related to some mysql-client package

```
Uncaught exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/my-app/some/path/sqlalchemy_db_profiling.py", line 10, in <module>
    from MySQLdb.converters import conversions, escape
  File "/Users/myname/my-app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/myname/my-app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): 
  Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib/libssl.1.1.dylib
      Referenced from: /Users/myname/my-app/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
      Reason: image not found
```

these are my dependencies on `requirements.txt`:

```
Flask==1.1.2
Flask-Login==0.5.0
Flask-Security==3.0.0
Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.4.4
gevent==1.5.0
SQLAlchemy==1.3.20
mysqlclient==1.4.6
PyMySQL==0.10.1
Flask-Compress==1.8.0
Flask-HTTPAuth==3.3.0
```

**Environment**:

- OS: macOS 11.4 (Big Sur)
- Python: pyenv Python 3.7.10
- Connector/C: Homebrew mysql-client 8.0.29
- Openssl: Homebrew openssl@1.1

**note**: my app ran well until today. This morning I ran `brew update && brew upgrade` and since then I get above error.

when I check whats under `/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib` here is what I get:

```
> ls /usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib
libmysqlclient.21.dylib libmysqlclient.a        libmysqlclient.dylib    pkgconfig
```

Answer (score 0):

solution from here: https://github.com/PyMySQL/mysqlclient/issues/546

- Create clean venv
- Clear pip cache. (wheel cache may contain old binary linking old client library).
- Follow what brew info mysql-client said. e.g. export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/lib/pkgconfig"
- Install again.